# Other uses of the particle に in お兄ちゃんには見つからない

Tags: particles, particle-に

I'm reading a story and two siblings are playing 'hide and seek'. The younger one, after finding a hiding place, says:

> ここならお兄ちゃんには絶対に見つからないよ

ここなら means 'if here' that is, from the context, 'if I hide in here...'

The rest of the sentence, I can tell, have the general meaning of "if I hide in here, my brother will absolutely not find me". But breaking down the sentence to pieces... what is the role of お兄ちゃんには? お兄ちゃん is not a location so に has little sense (to me) when applied to it.

What's going on?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14):

This に is not a location marker. In [this article about the particle に](http://japanese.about.com/library/weekly/aa090901a.htm):

> **Source**
>
> "Ni" indicates an agent or a source in passive or causative verbs. It translates into "by" or "from".
>
> - 母にしかられた。    I was scolded by my mother.
> - トムに英語を教えてもらった。    I was taught English by Tom.

The verb in question, 見つかる, is categorized as a *passive-like verb* (受動詞) by some linguists, and it functions as if it were passive even though there is no れる/られる. Such verbs include (but are not limited to):

- ～に見つかる　to be found by ～
- ～に教わる　to be taught by ～
- ～に捕まる　to be caught by ～
- ～に負ける　to be defeated by ～
- ～に破れる　to be defeated by ～
- ～に知れる　to come to be known to ～

List taken from [this article](http://www.lingua.tsukuba.ac.jp/ippan/TWPL0/TWPL05_31/2_meng2012.pdf).

Practically, I think you can forget the grammatical term and just memorize that these verbs always take に.

Comment: Does 付ける also constitute a passive-like verb (受動詞)?