# Book title 『誰も戦争を教えられない』

Tags: grammar

> 誰も戦争を教えられない

Is 教えられない 可能形 or 受身形? I don't have a specific context. It's the title of a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, this can mean both "No one can teach" (potential) and "No one is taught" (passive), but in 99% of the cases this should mean "No one can teach". This is partly because a ["passive-like"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30578/5010) verb 教わる ("to learn", "to be taught") is usually used to express the passive meaning: 誰も戦争を教わらない ("No one will learn war"). Similarly, 捕まえられない almost always means "(someone) cannot arrest" because we normally use 捕まらない for the passive meaning. In addition, "No one learns war" simply looks counterfactual and makes less sense to me as a book title.

Judging from [the review](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4062816067/), this title implies no one in Japan understands how real wars look.