# What is the difference between 知れる and 知られる(passive form)?

Tags: word-choice

Examples:
物事が多くの人に**知れる**こと vs 物事が多くの人に**知られる**こと

"the condition of things being known by many people"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

知られる is a simple passive form of 知る "to be known".

知れる is a [passive-like verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30578/5010) which can mean the same thing as 知られる, but it also has several distinct meanings.

1. "～ is known" (Semantically very close to 知られる, but sounds more literary and stiff. 知れる cannot be used as ["suffer passive"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1777/5010), either)

   > - 会社に知れたら困る。 (=会社に知られたら困る)
   > - 名の知れた店 (=名の知られた店 =有名な店)
2. "to be (self-)evident", "to be easily understandable", "it goes without saying", "needless to say"

   > - 原因はすぐにそれと知れた
   > - 行方が知れない　(someone) is missing
   > - あんなことを言うなんて、[気が知れない](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%B0%97%E3%81%8C%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)
   > - 金がないのは先から知れたことだ
   > - [言わずと知れた](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%A8%80%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A8%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F)
3. "to seem trivial", "to be not really great", "to be not as good as one may expect"

   > - 絵がうまいといっても、[たかが知れている](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%AB%98%E3%81%8C%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B)。
   > - 財産といっても知れたものだ。

Examples are taken from 明鏡国語辞典 第二版.

Comment: Can 知れる also take a pure potential form (of 知る) meaning? That is, can it also just mean "able to know"?

Comment: @George Yes it's possible to say something like 辞書を読めばその単語の意味が知れる, but 分かる is much more common for this meaning.